# how to submit to google form without redirecting to it's page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i'm trying to make a pwa ( progressive web app ) that is basically a form that submits to a google form so i can have the data stored in a google sheet.
my problem is when i click submit the original google page load. i attempted to remove it by adding a `target="dummyframe"` in the `<form>` with an empty iframe that works but the data doesn't auto-erase from the cases so the user will feel like it didn't submit so the solution is to relad the page when submitted but i couldn't do that so this is the code

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe"></iframe>
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/...." target="dummyframe" method="POST" id="mG61Hd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `form` and `iframe`, you should look at the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API.

fetch allows you to make calls to websites, like the browser itself does, and you can get the results back and process them.

I don't know the Google API well enough to give you a specific example.